# Can someone help me dismiss Game Center when the dismiss button is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am having trouble dismissing Game Center in my app. I have set the func gameCenterViewControllerDidFisnish, but it is not being called. I also remembered to set         gc.gameCenterDelegate = self and even put GKGameCenterControllerDelegate in my class header. Can someone take a look and tell me what I have missed?

```
import AVFoundation
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GameKit

class MainMenu: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
    
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("clicked")
    }
  
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()    
    var superbounceLogo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "superbounceLogo.png")
    var playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton.png")
    var leaderboardButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "leaderboardButton.png")
    var achievementButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "achievementsButton.png")
    var instructionsButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "instructionsButton.png")
    var playbuttonHoverAAs = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton.png")
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        instructionsButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 570)
        instructionsButton.zPosition = 1
        instructionsButton.setScale(0.7)
        self.addChild(instructionsButton)
        
        achievementButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 480)
        achievementButton.zPosition = 1
        achievementButton.setScale(0.7)
        self.addChild(achievementButton)
        
        playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 300)
        playButton.zPosition = 1
        playButton.setScale(0.7)
        
        self.addChild(playButton)
        
        leaderboardButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 390 )
        leaderboardButton.zPosition = 1
        leaderboardButton.setScale(0.7)
        self.addChild(leaderboardButton)
        
        superbounceLogo.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: 400)
        superbounceLogo.zPosition = 1
        superbounceLogo.setScale(1.5)
        self.addChild(superbounceLogo)
        
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval){
        
    }
    
    func showLeaderboard(){
        let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        let gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        
        gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
        gc.viewState = .leaderboards
        gc.leaderboardIdentifier = "superbounceleaderboard"
        vc!.present(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            
            
            if playButton.frame.contains(location) {
                print("clicked")
                //playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButtonHover.png")
                
                let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clickSound.wav", ofType: nil)!
                    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: sound)
                              
                        do{
                            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                            audioPlayer.play()
                            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
                                } catch {
                                  print(error)
                }
            }
                if let playScene = PlayScene(fileNamed: "PlayScene") {
                    let playScene = PlayScene(size: CGSize(width:640, height: 960))

                    self.view?.presentScene(playScene, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1))

                }
            
            if leaderboardButton.frame.contains(location) {
                print("clicked")
                showLeaderboard()
                    
                
                let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clickSound.wav", ofType: nil)!
                    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: sound)
                              
                        do{
                            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                            audioPlayer.play()
                            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
                                } catch {
                                  print(error)
                }
            }
            
            
            if instructionsButton.frame.contains(location) {
                print("clicked")
                
                let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clickSound.wav", ofType: nil)!
                    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: sound)
                              
                        do{
                            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                            audioPlayer.play()
                            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
                                } catch {
                                  print(error)
                }
            
                
                if let instructionScene = InstructionsScene(fileNamed: "InstructionsScene") {
                    let instructionScene = InstructionsScene(size: CGSize(width:640, height: 960))

                    self.view?.presentScene(instructionScene, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1))

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }}
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you remove any code that's not related to the problem so people can help you better. There are also some formatting issues you might want to fix. And on a side note, you probably shouldn't use `AVAudioPlayer` for what is, I'm assuming, a short-length sound. Better to use SpriteKit's `playSoundFileNamed(_:waitForCompletion:)` for short sounds and `AVAudioPlayer` for music/long sounds.

Comment: Have you check, wether the gameCenterDelegate method is called? I would say it should be `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of `gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do everything concerning Game Center in the GameViewController. I was trying to do everything in individual scene.